# dcgettext is not working in localization

Tags: php, mysql, gettext

Subject : To get translation from two mo files.

I am using getext extension of php for translation.
gettext() function works fine but when I want to get translation from another mo file using dcgettext() function  at the same time it returns only id instead of translation.

Following is my code for loading mo file and get translation

```
clearstatcache();
define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('./'));
define('LOCALE_DIR', PROJECT_DIR .'/locale');
define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US');
$encoding = 'UTF-8';
$locale = (isset($_GET['lang']))? $_GET['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;
// gettext setup
T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$our_domain = 'message';
T_bindtextdomain($our_domain, LOCALE_DIR);
T_bind_textdomain_codeset($our_domain, $encoding);
T_textdomain($our_domain);

echo T_("dash_home");//from message.mo
echo '<br>';
echo T_dcgettext('de_CH' , 'abc1' , 5 );//from brand.mo
```

//message.mo path
local/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/message.mo
//brand.mo path
local/de_CH/LC_MESSAGES/brand.mo